# Convert big mobi file to pdf

Tags: file-converter, mobi

I have a mobi file, sized 225 MB, which I want to convert to pdf. There are dozens of websites, for this type of conversion, but none works for this file, because the size of the file is too large. I have also tried software like “Epub Converter” or “Epubor ultimate converter”, but unfortunately this didn’t work either. Does anyone have an idea how to do this conversion?

Comment: Nice command line tool: https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html Install calibre, it is not an online service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Calibre software, as mentioned in the comment?

It can be donwloaded from  https://calibre-ebook.com/download for Windows, Linux, and Mac.

It has a GUI, and also, as mentioned in the comment, it can be used from command-line/ terminal.